# Cordova Plugin to identify incoming call number in android?

Tags: android, cordova

I am trying to get the incoming call number from my cordova android plugin. Able to get the Phone State using TELEPHONYMANGER.PHONE_STATE_CHANGED. But unable to get the incoming call number. BroadcastReceiver's Intent provides the option to get the incoming call number. But BroadcastReceiver's onReceive function is not triggered. Please help.

```
package io.infonion.calldetail;

import org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin;
import org.apache.cordova.CallbackContext;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import org.apache.cordova.PluginResult;
import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONArray;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
public class CallDetail extends CordovaPlugin {
    CallStateListener listener;
    IntentFilter intentFilter;
    Context maincontext;
        public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
            Toast.makeText(cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "first", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if (listener == null) {
                listener = new CallStateListener();
                listener.setCordovaContext(cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext());
                listener.setCallbackContext(callbackContext);
                Toast.makeText(cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "fourth", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                intentFilter = new IntentFilter() ;
                intentFilter.addAction(TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED);
                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(super.webView.getContext()).registerReceiver(listener,intentFilter);
                //registerReceiver(listener, intentFilter);
                Toast.makeText(cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "fifth", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return true;
        }




    }
     class CallStateListener extends BroadcastReceiver {

        private CallbackContext callbackContext;
       private Context cordovaContext;

            public void setCallbackContext(CallbackContext callbackContext) {
                Toast.makeText(cordovaContext, "third", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                this.callbackContext = callbackContext;                
            }

            public void setCordovaContext(Context cordovaContext) {
                Toast.makeText(cordovaContext, "second", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                this.cordovaContext = cordovaContext;                
            }




            @Override
            public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
                String act=intent.getAction();
                String number="";
                Toast.makeText(cordovaContext, "Sixth", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                if(intent.getAction().equals("TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED")){

                    String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
                    Toast.makeText(cordovaContext, state, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    if(state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)){
                        //  Log.d(TAG, "Inside Extra state off hook");
                     number = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
                        Toast.makeText(cordovaContext, "EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        //   Log.e(TAG, "outgoing number : " + number);              
                    }       

                    else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)){   
                        //   Log.e(TAG, "Inside EXTRA_STATE_RINGING");
                         number = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
                        Toast.makeText(cordovaContext, "RINGING", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        //   Log.e(TAG, "incoming number : " + number);
                    }
                    else if(state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)){
                        Toast.makeText(cordovaContext, "EXTRA_STATE_IDLE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        //  Log.d(TAG, "Inside EXTRA_STATE_IDLE");
                    }   

                    PluginResult result = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, number);
                    result.setKeepCallback(true);
                    callbackContext.sendPluginResult(result);
                } 





            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's late to answer but may this help other people :
Creating instance "new CallStateListener()" for the receiver will not trigger the onReceive method.
Your receiver is not working, it should be declared at AndroidManifest.xml inside the tag **application** .

So you should first make **static** the class CallStateListener :

```
public static CallStateListener extends BrodcastReceiver {}
```

and add these lines on your **plugin.xml** file inside :

```
<config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/manifest/application">

        <receiver android:name="io.infonion.calldetail.CallDetail$CallStateListener"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
</config-file>
```